# Logger implementation to use in spring4d

Tags: spring4d

I have tried TTextLogAppender and TLogFileAppender and noticed that between app restarts the logfile is cleared and did not notice any property / method that would change this behaviour. I like log4net, especially the ability to rollover logging (create new files) on filesize / periods and just appends log data irrespective of app restarts etc. Does any of the existing appenders in spring4d expose similar behaviour to this? Should I rather register log4d as a logger instance in my container?

Comment: This is a good point please create a feature request (issue) on bitbucket. Or better yet submit a pull request ;-)

Comment: Thanks, so I am not configuring the appenders incorrectly then it seems. None of the appenders operate as I had mentioned above?